# How to Set value in text box using nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to Set value in text box using nodes?

```
var tot = parseFloat(parseFloat(shortageval) - parseFloat(singval)).toFixed(3);
$($this).parents('tr').prevAll('tr').find('id=sishr11').innerhtml=tot;
```

please help.

Comment: It depends on the HTML structure, you may need to provide that as well. However, try replacing `.innerhtml=tot` with `.html(tot)` because `find` returns an array not a DOM element.

Comment: `$($this)`? or `$(this)` ?

Comment: $($this)? this only i used

Comment: use `.val(tot)` .Textbox has value. `$($this).parents('tr').prevAll('tr').find('[id=sishr11]').val(tot);`

Comment: var tot = parseFloat(parseFloat(shortageval) - parseFloat(singval)).toFixed(3); alert(tot);
             $($this).parents('tr').prevAll('tr').find('id=sishr11').val(tot);

Comment: Show also your HTML structure

Comment: tnx shaunakde it works ! tnx all for ur answers

Comment: here is the working code Raptor                                   var tot = parseFloat(parseFloat(shortageval) - parseFloat(singval)).toFixed(3);                             alert(tot);             $($this).parents('tr').prevAll('tr').find('[id=sishr11]').val(tot);

Comment: You can simplify the code to `$('#sishr11').val(tot)`, since IDs have to be unique.

Comment: yes bt i am using autogenerating rows, so only i used nodes dude

Comment: Then you should probably fix your code and use classes instead of IDs ... dude.

Comment: how felix ? since i am a fresher to programming, kindly, suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you...

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'sample1.xml' );
$musiclist = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "song" );
foreach( $musiclist as $song )
{

 $artists = $song->getElementsByTagName( "artist" );
 $artist = $artists->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
?>
<input type="text" id="artist" name="artist" value="<?php echo $artist;  ?>"tabindex="1"/>
```

This is the XML Sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<musiclist>
<song>
<title></title>
<artist></artist>
<url></url>
</song>
</musiclist>
```